# How to optimize this long running sqlite3 query for finding duplicates?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite

I've got this rather insane query for finding **all but the FIRST** record with a duplicate value. It takes a substantially long time to run on 38000 records; about 50 seconds.

```
UPDATE exr_exrresv
    SET mh_duplicate = 1
WHERE exr_exrresv._id IN
(
     SELECT F._id
     FROM exr_exrresv AS F
     WHERE Exists 
     (
          SELECT PHONE_NUMBER, 
                 Count(_id)
          FROM exr_exrresv
          WHERE exr_exrresv.PHONE_NUMBER = F.PHONE_NUMBER 
                AND exr_exrresv.PHONE_NUMBER != '' 
                AND mh_active = 1 AND mh_duplicate = 0
          GROUP BY exr_exrresv.PHONE_NUMBER
          HAVING Count(exr_exrresv._id) > 1)
     )
AND exr_exrresv._id NOT IN
(
   SELECT Min(_id)
   FROM exr_exrresv AS F
   WHERE Exists 
   (
       SELECT PHONE_NUMBER,
       Count(_id)
       FROM exr_exrresv
       WHERE exr_exrresv.PHONE_NUMBER = F.PHONE_NUMBER 
             AND exr_exrresv.PHONE_NUMBER != '' 
             AND mh_active = 1 
             AND mh_duplicate = 0
       GROUP BY exr_exrresv.PHONE_NUMBER
       HAVING Count(exr_exrresv._id) > 1
   )
       GROUP BY PHONE_NUMBER
);
```

Any tips on how to optimize it or how I should begin to go about it? I've checked out the query plan but I'm really not sure how to begin improving it.  Temp tables? Better query?

Here is the explain query plan output:

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE exr_exrresv USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~12 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 0
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE exr_exrresv AS F (~500000 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE exr_exrresv USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (PHONE_NUMBER=? AND mh_active=? AND mh_duplicate=?) (~7 rows)
1|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 2
2|0|0|SCAN TABLE exr_exrresv AS F (~500000 rows)
2|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE exr_exrresv USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (PHONE_NUMBER=? AND mh_active=? AND mh_duplicate=?) (~7 rows)
3|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
2|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

Any tips would be much appreciated. :)

Also, I am using Ruby to make the sql query so if it makes more sense for the logic to leave SQL and be written in Ruby, that's possible.

The schema is as follows, and you can use sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c07e

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
OPPORTUNITY_ID varchar(50)
CREATEDDATE varchar(50)
FIRSTNAME varchar(50)
LASTNAME varchar(50)
MAILINGSTREET varchar(50)
MAILINGCITY varchar(50)
MAILINGSTATE varchar(50)
MAILINGZIPPOSTALCODE varchar(50)
EMAIL varchar(50)
CONTACT_PHONE varchar(50)
PHONE_NUMBER varchar(50)
CallFromWeb varchar(50)
OPPORTUNITY_ORIGIN varchar(50)
PROJECTED_LTV varchar(50)
MOVE_IN_DATE varchar(50)
mh_processed_date varchar(50)
mh_control INTEGER
mh_active INTEGER
mh_duplicate INTEGER
```

Comment: much better if you can add the schema of the tables

Comment: Why do you allow duplicates into your database in the first place? Is it required? Struggling to see why you would allow this to happen? Also some table structures would allow us to actually help. See JW comment above.

Comment: Yep, can't do much without knowing your data structure - put it on SQL fiddle if you can and give us a link.

Comment: First you have a mismatch in parentheses.

Comment: Adding the table structure now. You'll see it in the schema... the records are unique if you compare all of the data, but two records could have the same phone number. The goal is to mark any records that have the same phone number as a record with duplicate information (mh_duplicate = 1).

Comment: Did you see my post?  Were my assumptions correct?

Comment: @sgeddes I'm checking it out now. Just updated my sqlfiddle with sample data, then I'm testing your query out on real data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/dc61e/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your post, it looks like you are trying to update the `mh_duplicate` column for any record that has the same phone number if it's not the first record with that phone number?

If that's correct, I think this should get you the id's to update (you may need to add back your appropriate where criteria) -- from there, the Update is straight-forward:

```
SELECT e._Id
FROM exr_exrresv e
JOIN
 ( SELECT t.Phone_Number
    FROM exr_exrresv t
    GROUP BY t.Phone_Number
    HAVING COUNT (t.Phone_Number) > 1
  ) e2 ON e.Phone_Number = e2.Phone_Number
LEFT JOIN 
 ( SELECT MIN(t2._Id) as KeepId
    FROM exr_exrresv t2
    GROUP BY t2.Phone_Number
  ) e3 ON e._Id = e3.KeepId
WHERE e3.KeepId is null
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/359f5/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This considers a record duplicate if there exists an active record with a matching phone_number and with a lesser _id. (No grouping or counting needed.)

```
update exr_exrresv
    set mh_duplicate = 1
where exr_exrresv._id in (
  select target._id
  from exr_exrresv as target
  where target.phone_number != ''
  and target.mh_active = 1
  and exists (
    select null from exr_exrresv as probe
    where probe.phone_number = target.phone_number 
    and probe.mh_active = 1
    and probe._id < target._id
  )
)
```

This query will be greatly aided if there exists an index on phone_number, ideally on `exr_exrresv (phone_number, _id)`

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1e7bc/1/0)

Comment: While I liked the idea of this one, it took well over 10 minutes to run vs the one I started with (2:56 seconds) and the one provided by sgeddes (38 seconds). Perhaps I was doing something wrong, but whatever I did sure doesn't make this a good query for the job.

Comment: @JeremyBaker Try adding an index on (phone_number, _id).